# Find and replace Sublime regex in files

Tags: regex, replace, sublimetext2

This shouldn't be a hard one to achieve but after reading about regex I still can't wrap my head around this. My problem is that I need to find **&#243;** characters between
(val=='') and replace them with **\u00F3** (first (val==' is the start sequence and the second one the end).

This would occur in about 80 files so it has to be pretty precise. The number of characters are different in each block, and there are a couple of replacements to do in each film - but I guess Sublime takes care of that.

Example, part of the code in

```
   function Update_qu887() {
     var val = VarQuestion_0010.getValue()
     radio891.objLyr.doc.getElementById("radio891id").checked=(val=='got&#243;wk\u0119, u015Brodki trwa\u0142e, kredyty, lokaty mi\u0119dzybankowe czynne, papiery warto\u015Bciowe oraz inne aktywa')
     radio893.objLyr.doc.getElementById("radio893id").checked=(val=='got&#243;wk\u0119, \u015Brodki trwa\u0142e, kredyty, lokaty mi\u0119dzybankowe czynne, aktywa trwa\u0142e, kredyty hipoteczne')
     radio895.objLyr.doc.getElementById("radio895id").checked=(val=='lokaty mi\u0119dzybankowe czynne, papiery warto\u015Bciowe, inne aktywa, klient&#243;w instytucjonalnych, klient&#243;w indywidualnych')
     qu887.hasBeenProcessed=false;
    }
```

You can see the  **&#243;** that needs to be replaced with this code **\u00F3** so it will work properly as a whole. so the end code would look like this

```
  function Update_qu887() {
     var val = VarQuestion_0010.getValue()
     radio891.objLyr.doc.getElementById("radio891id").checked=(val=='got\u00F3wk\u0119, u015Brodki trwa\u0142e, kredyty, lokaty mi\u0119dzybankowe czynne, papiery warto\u015Bciowe oraz inne aktywa')
     radio893.objLyr.doc.getElementById("radio893id").checked=(val=='got\u00F3wk\u0119, \u015Brodki trwa\u0142e, kredyty, lokaty mi\u0119dzybankowe czynne, aktywa trwa\u0142e, kredyty hipoteczne')
     radio895.objLyr.doc.getElementById("radio895id").checked=(val=='lokaty mi\u0119dzybankowe czynne, papiery warto\u015Bciowe, inne aktywa, klient\u00F3w instytucjonalnych, klient\u00F3w indywidualnych')
     qu887.hasBeenProcessed=false;
    }
```

Comment: I would recommend to add exact example (what I have and what I expect after) for better readability & understanding.

Answer (score 0):

The following regex will find all `(val=='xxx` followed by `&#243;` and replace them with `(val=='xxx\u00F3` (xxx can be any string that doesn't conatain a `'`)

```
s/(\(val=='[^']*?)&#243;/\1\\u00F3/g
```

Notes:

`(` and `\` are special characters in regex, so they have been prefixed with a `\` in the regex.

`(val=='[^']*?` is captured by enclosing it in parenthesis. The captured value is used in the replacement  as `\1`. `[^']*?` matches any sequence of characters except `'`.

You didn't specify which syntax you wanted. I think the regex above will work with perl and sed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if you look closely you'll see that &amp;#243 doesn't always follow the words **got** but can be everywhere in between two apostrophes.

Comment: Thank you I'll check this out in the near future, and let you know if this works as it should.